# C++ Passing An Int, Error Saying It's A Double

Tags: c++, error-handling, binary

I am currently working on an assignment where we're making an assembler using c++. I have got as far as having the code distinguish when a number is input, and am trying to get the program to change the relevant bits in a 16 bit array to the required binary number.

The problem is that after the power is calculated, the remainder of the input number and the first power exceeding it is assigned to an int, yet passing it back into dec_to_bin() I am getting the following error.

> assembler.cpp: In function ‘void dec_to_bin(int, int*)’:
>   assembler.cpp:135:32: error: invalid conversion from ‘double (*)(double, double)throw ()’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
>      dec_to_bin(remainder, pointer);

```
//*pointer points to an array[16]
void dec_to_bin(int num, int *pointer)
{
    //Base cases
    if(num == 2)
    {
        pointer[14] = 1;
        return;
    }
    else if(num == 1)
    {
        pointer[15] = 1;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int power = 0;
        //power function outlined below. The inbuilt pow(a, b) returns a
        //double and gave the same problem, so I tried this instead.
        while(PowerFunc(2, power) < num)
        {
            power++;
        }
        //Problem arises here. remainder is assigned as an int
        //Using typeinfo shows it as an int, yet passing it a few lines
        //down gives the quoted error.
        int remainder = PowerFunc(2, power)-num;
        pointer[16-power] = 1;
    }
    if(remainder == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //Line that throws the error. Saying remainder is a double.
        dec_to_bin(remainder, pointer);
    }
}
//Power function to replace pow(a, b). Not ideal but it works.
int PowerFunc(int number, int powernum)
{
    if(powernum == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(powernum == 1)
    {
        return number;
    }
    else
    {
        return number * PowerFunc(number, powernum-1);
    }
}
```

This has me stumped honestly. At first I had thought using pow(a, b) and assigned it to an int would just splice the decimal part off, but even making my own power function is still telling me my int is a double.

Comment: Do consider calculating the powers incrementally, just update it for each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
    int remainder = PowerFunc(2, power)-num;
```

appears between curly braces-delimited block under `else`, so the range of the `remainder` variable extends just one line down. The `remainder` in

```
    if(remainder == 0)
```

and in

```
    dec_to_bin(remainder, pointer);
```

is some other entity, by coincidence having the same name. You can verify that by renaming your `remainder` to anything else, say `myremainder`...

Additional notes:
consider replacing `if(powernum == 0)` with `if(powernum <= 0)` — that will save you lots of calculation in case of negative exponent.

I'd also suggest to replace the recursion

```
return number * PowerFunc(number, powernum-1);
```

with iteration:

```
int result = 1;
while(powernum-- >= 0)
    result *= number;
return result;
```

Comment: Well that was quite obvious. Fresh eyes always help. Initialising the remainder variable at the start of dec_to_bin worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, `remainder` is also a function declared elsewhere, and the compiler complains that `dec_to_bin` takes a `double` as its first argument and not a pointer to a function of type `double (*)(double, double)`.

At the point that you call `dec_to_bin(remainder, pointer);` variable `remainder` declared in the `else` scope is not visible.

You also have a problem with your `if(remainder == 0)` since it will always evaluates to false.